# CoffeeScript class field is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

This code is passing in a function and is not carrying over the state of my EmployeesController object. What can i do to bind my EmployessController object to the focus event?

```
class @EmployeesController 
  constructor: (@dateInput) ->
    @dateInput.focus(@searchInputGainedFocus)


  searchInputGainedFocus: ->
    console.debug @dateInput
```

In other words, console.debug prints undefined when i give dateInput focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ["fat arrow" (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to bind `searchInputGainedFocus` to the object:

> The fat arrow `=>` can be used to both define a function, and to bind it to the current value of `this`, right on the spot. This is helpful when using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, [...]

So define `searchInputGainedFocus` like this:

```
class @EmployeesController 
  constructor: (@dateInput) ->
    @dateInput.focus(@searchInputGainedFocus)

  searchInputGainedFocus: =>
    console.debug @dateInput
```